# SQL Server process each row in table - Cursor or While loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am dumping all the file names in directory into a temp table using `xp_dirtree.`

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Subdirectory VARCHAR(512), Depth INT, xFile INT);

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Subdirectory, Depth, xFile)
   EXEC xp_dirtree 'D:\log\Day_20140301',0,1

SELECT Subdirectory AS Filename 
FROM #TempTable 
WHERE subdirectory LIKE '%.log';

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

I use each file names in this table for Bulk insert.

Would a cursor be good or a while loop?

Currently using while loop to loop through each record.

Heard many negative things about cursor. Open to all suggestion for the same.

Comment: A while loop is just a cursor in disguise... but here in this case, I don't see any other solution, really. There's no way to do this in a set-based way - you'll need to do a row-by-agonizing-row loop and execute the bulk insert for each file.

Comment: Yes. Would using a cursor make any difference or the performance will be the same? The directory has around 300-400 files for daily bulk.

Comment: Both approaches will have a similar performance characteristic, no significant improvement is to be expected from using a cursor over a while loop ....

Comment: Could you abandon the cursor approach altogether and create a master log file of all the log files you intend to gather together?  Then do one insert from there.  I am thinking you could take advantage of a high level language to perform the IO combining of files and then a simple SQL statement to bulk insert like you've got.  Perhaps even a CLR?

Comment: And when people ask why there are cursors when they are performance problems, this is the answer, to do these kinds of tasks where a set-based solution is not avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, "No matter" is probably the right answer. While or cursor over 1k records will cost you approximately nothing comparing to the IO latency and CPU used by bulk insert. I suppose, optimizing loaded files structure and corresponding tables should take the lead.